# How to use a random proxy from a dictionary of proxies for sending a get request to a url?

Tags: python

I want to use a random proxy from a dictionary of 10 proxies to send a get request. The proxies are authentic and i am using integrated authentication.

I will be using the code:

```
prox = {"https" : "https://user:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx", "https" : 
         "https://user:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx", "https":
              "https://user:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx"}

k = prox.keys()[random.randint(0,len(prox))]

NewArrUrl = 'https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/en/xx/secxn/xxxxxxxx'

responseNewArr = requests.get(url = NewArrUrl, verify = False, headers = headersNewArr, allow_redirects = False, proxies = ??????? )
```

I have tried `random.choice(list(prox.items()))` but it throws:

```
no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'.
```

I don't get why is there a need to define `'if proxy == None'`

Comment: `prox` is not a valid Python dictionary. Please post actual or working code.

Comment: Store your proxies in a list, select a random item and use it to create a `proxies` dictionary.

Comment: sorry i forgot to insert a double comma. please check it now :)

Comment: 1. `prox.items() ` iterates on the (key, value) pairs so it's never going to return a proxy; and 2. Python's dictionaries are not multidicts, you get one value for each key, so for your example here you'll have a single value mapped to a single key `https`.

Comment: so what shall i do to retrieve the whole pair for proxy parameter

Comment: requests wants `proxies` to be a mapping of scheme to address, so you want to define a list of dicts, and pass `proxies=random.choice(list_of_proxy_mappings)`.

Comment: thanx man.. thanx a lot. t.m. adam and Maskinn. lemme do it

Comment: but how will a dictionary element be converted into a list element as the former has a 'colon' ( : ) sign. the whole element cant be converted into string or it will create problem when it is being made a dict element

Comment: okay thank you all. i will mark ur comments as answer. thanx a lot